# tar: short read

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

I get an error when I uncompress my `tar`.

I do this:

```
tar xvf VM_DECOMPTES.tar
```

and after some time I get the following error:

```
tar: short read
```

What is going wrong here?

> tar: unrecognized option `--version' BusyBox
>   v1.9.1-VMware-visor-klnext-2965 (2010-04-19 12:53:48 PDT) multi-call
>   binary

Comment: On what system are you trying to untar this archive? Have you tried to `touch file && tar cvf mytar.tar file && tar xvf mytar.tar`  and see if the error is still there?

Comment: What `tar` implementation and version? `tar --version`? Which Linux distribution?

Comment: You might want to try using an *actual* version of GNU tar as opposed to the one integrated into busybox...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that your tarfile is corrupted or truncated.

The [header of a tarfile](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) contains a `size` field that contains the length of the file.¹ If the actual file is shorter than the header says it should be, tar will try to read past the filesystem end of file and get back a read shorter than it expected, thus generating the message you see.

¹ This feature dates to when tar was used primarily for Tape ARchiving where you could only know the length of a "file" by reading until you hit an EOF marker on the tape. It was retained for backwards compatibility and also provides a nice (if kinda cheap) check on header and file consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this message appears if the tar archive is incomplete. If you run `tar tvf ./VM_DECOMPTEST.tar` it will check the tar file for inconsistencies.

Comment: tar: invalid gzip magic

Comment: @Mercer because that is not a `.gz` file. You are ignoring things that were provided to you to test. What tar version are you using? As earlier mentioned `tar --version` , then try to tar a file yourself and extract it. See my first comment. Update your post with tests you performed.

Comment: @Kamiccolo i have edit my post

Comment: @kamiccolo Please don't add the `-z` flag automatically when it's already mentioned that it's a *.tar* file, not a *.tgz* file...

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the version of tar that you're running, especially if you are unable to reproduce this issue with GNU tar.

You can build a new version of busybox for your platform by running something like the following commands:

```
$ wget https://busybox.net/downloads/busybox-1.31.0.tar.bz2
$ tar xjf busybox-1.31.0.tar.bz2
$ cd busybox-1.31.0
$ LDFLAGS=--static make -j16  # if applicable: CROSS_COMPILE=...-linux-gnu-
```

In particular, there seems to be some sort of bug in unpacking with busybox v1.22.1 (other versions too, perhaps) that has been fixed by v1.31.0.